# Using OnMethodBoundaryAspect across multiple projects

Tags: postsharp

I am having a problem with OnMethodBoundaryAspect used by different projects. In particular I have
- root website which is MVC
- sub-website in ASP.NET
- business & data access layers called both by MVC and ASP.NET

I have implemented my own tracing class VerboseTracing : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, within a separate stand-alone logging DLL.

I have added the attribute at the assembly level in both MVC and ASP.NET project

What I am seeing is that the tracing is only outputting for methods in the MVC project. All the projects reference the logging DLL, as indicated in [Using PostSharp OnExceptionAspect across mulit projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976417/using-postsharp-onexceptionaspect-across-mulit-projects).

Any help would be appreciated as I REALLY REALLY need the logging to work in the non-MVC projects.

I am attaching the VerboseTracing class.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have PostSharp NuGet package installed for your ASP.NET project?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the **AttributeTargetAssemblies** attribute parameter.

Here is how I have been able to use aspects across multiple projects. The only difference being I am using a project rather than direct assembly reference to the aspect code.

I add the below line, (with proper assembly and namespace) for every other assembly\namespace I need to add aspects to, that my web project code uses.

> [assembly: ProfileAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies =
>   "BusinessLogic.Assembly.Name", AttributeTargetTypes =
>   "BusinessLogic.Assembly.Namspeace.*")]

Answer (score 0):

I think [AlexD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177460/alexd) might be on to something. You should include your logging DLL, and any dependencies the logging project requires to run inside of your ASP.NET project. So I would assume the logging project depends on PostSharp, so PostSharp should also be installed to the ASP.NET project.